# Pandas row value based on column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks something like that:

```
A1   A2   A3   A4   B   C   D
0     2   9     0   9   7   2
7     6   7     3   6   8   4     
3     7   4     9   2   1   1
```

I want to create a new column, call it E, whose values come from columns A1, A2, A3, or A4 depending on the value of column D.

For example, if D=2, then the value for E is taken from column A2. My new dataframe would look like this:

```
A1   A2   A3   A4   B   C   D   E
0     2   9     0   9   7   2   2
7     6   7     3   6   8   4   3  
3     7   4     9   2   1   1   3
```

I have tried using df.apply but that doesn't seem to work...
Any idea on how that can be done?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if D does not equal to 2? Do we pad the default value, which is 3?

Answer (score 2):

We just need `lookup` (see [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html))

```
df.lookup(df.index,df.columns[df.D-1])
Out[309]: array([2, 3, 3], dtype=int64)
```

After assign it back

```
df['E']=df.lookup(df.index,df.columns[df.D-1])
df
Out[311]: 
   A1  A2  A3  A4  B  C  D  E
0   0   2   9   0  9  7  2  2
1   7   6   7   3  6  8  4  3
2   3   7   4   9  2  1  1  3
```

Update

```
df.D.astype(str).map(dict(zip(df.columns.str[-1],df.columns)))
Out[316]: 
0    A2
1    A4
2    A1
Name: D, dtype: object
```

Then

```
df.lookup(df.index,df.D.astype(str).map(dict(zip(df.columns.str[-1],df.columns))))
Out[317]: array([2, 3, 3], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Thanks Wen! What if there are columns to the left of A1, A2, A3, and A4? Does your method still apply?

Comment: @user2920100 if you df.D 's value always refer to the columns position of whole df, it should always work

Comment: No, the df.D values don't necessarily refer to the column number; they actually refert to the last digit of the column header.